# Array combinatorics

Tags: arrays, ruby, cartesian-product

I am working in Ruby 2.7.

I have an Array, whose elements are one of three things: either a String or an Integer, or occasionally another Array with a pair of elements (this time, only Strings or Integers). There are no further levels of nesting for Arrays, by the definition of my problem.

Examples:

```
w = [1, 2, 'b', 4]
x = [[2, 'r'],[2, 'g']]
y = [[2, 'w']]
z = ['u', 6, [2, 'r']]
```

The context of the problem is that the inner arrays represent selectable alternatives for use in the outer array. I am looking for all possible ways to choose an element from each inner array, if present, and substitute that element into the outer array.

Examples:

```
f(w) = [ [1, 2, 'b', 4] ]
f(x) = [ [2, 2], [2, 'g'], ['r', 2], ['r', 'g'] ]
f(y) = [ [2], ['w'] ]
f(z) = [ ['u', 6, 2], ['u', 6, 'r'] ]
```

Order of elements in each selection (inner array of each solution) does not matter. Order of solutions in output also does not matter.

I can brute force an answer selecting/rejecting, transforming, and using Array#product; but I am looking for an approach that is as brief and elegant as possible.

Comment: Please rephrase your question using more precise language. The value of `x` and `f(x)` do not align with the phrasing in _I am looking for all possible ways to choose an element from each inner array, if present, and substitute that element into the outer array_ -- the two don't even remotely comport.

Comment: If you can brute force the answer, *post that code* and maybe we can optimize it. Forcing us to re-invent a solution from scratch is not constructive.

Answer (score 1):

The rules given in the question are unprecise and incomplete, so I've done my best to infer what they are.

**Code**

```
def doit(arr)
  if arr.size == 1
    e = arr.first
    return e.is_a?(Array) ? (arr.map { |f| [f] }) : arr
  end
  (first, *rest), other = arr.partition { |e| e.is_a?(Array) }
  return [arr] if first.nil?
  prod = first.product(*rest)
  return prod if other.empty?
  prod.flat_map { |a| other.map { |e| [e, *a] } }
end
```

See [Enumerable#partition](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition), [Array#product](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-product) and [Enumerable#flat_map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map).

**Examples**

```
doit [1, 2, 'b', 4]
  #=> [[1, 2, "b", 4]] 
doit [[2, 'r'],[2, 'g']]
  #=> [[2, 2], [2, "g"], ["r", 2], ["r", "g"]] 
doit [:a, [2, 'r'], :b, [2, 'g']]
  #=> [[:a, 2, 2], [:b, 2, 2], [:a, 2, "g"], [:b, 2, "g"],
  #    [:a, "r", 2], [:b, "r", 2], [:a, "r", "g"], [:b, "r", "g"]] 
doit [[2, 'w']]
  #=> [[[2, "w"]]] 
doit ['u', 6, [2, 'r']]
  #=> [["u", 2], [6, 2], ["u", "r"], [6, "r"]] 
doit [:a, [2, 3], :b, :c, [4, 5], :d, [6, 7]]
  #=> [[:a, 2, 4, 6], [:b, 2, 4, 6], [:c, 2, 4, 6], [:d, 2, 4, 6],
  #    [:a, 2, 4, 7], [:b, 2, 4, 7], [:c, 2, 4, 7], [:d, 2, 4, 7],
  #    [:a, 2, 5, 6], [:b, 2, 5, 6], [:c, 2, 5, 6], [:d, 2, 5, 6],
  #    [:a, 2, 5, 7], [:b, 2, 5, 7], [:c, 2, 5, 7], [:d, 2, 5, 7],
  #    [:a, 3, 4, 6], [:b, 3, 4, 6], [:c, 3, 4, 6], [:d, 3, 4, 6],
  #    [:a, 3, 4, 7], [:b, 3, 4, 7], [:c, 3, 4, 7], [:d, 3, 4, 7],
  #    [:a, 3, 5, 6], [:b, 3, 5, 6], [:c, 3, 5, 6], [:d, 3, 5, 6],
  #    [:a, 3, 5, 7], [:b, 3, 5, 7], [:c, 3, 5, 7], [:d, 3, 5, 7]]
```

Note that the return value for `doit [[2, 'w']]` is different than that given in the question.

**Explanation**

The steps are as follows.

```
arr = [:a, [2, 'r'], :b, [2, 'g']]

(first, *rest), other = arr.partition { |e| e.is_a?(Array) }
  #=> [[[2, "r"], [2, "g"]], [:a, :b]]
```

Ruby applies [array decomposition](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition) to the above expression to obtain values for `first`, `rest` and `other`:

```
first
  #=> [2, "r"] 
rest
  #=> [[2, "g"]] 
other
  #=> [:a, :b]
```

Continuing, because `first.nil? #=> false` in `return [arr] if first.nil?`, we do not return. Next:

```
prod = first.product(*rest)
  #=> [[2, 2], [2, "g"], ["r", 2], ["r", "g"]]
```

`other.empty? #=> false` in `return prod if other.empty?` so we do not return.

I can best explain the remaining calculations by inserting `puts` statement in the code and running it.

```
prod.flat_map do |a|
  puts "a = #{a}"
  other.map do |e|
    puts "  e = :#{e}"
    puts "    [e, *a] = #{[e, *a]}"
    [e, *a]
  end
end
  #=> [[:a, 2, 2], [:b, 2, 2], [:a, 2, "g"], [:b, 2, "g"],
  #    [:a, "r", 2], [:b, "r", 2], [:a, "r", "g"], [:b, "r", "g"]]
```

The following is displayed.

```
a = [2, 2]
  e = :a
    [e, *a] = [:a, 2, 2]
  e = :b
    [e, *a] = [:b, 2, 2]
a = [2, "g"]
  e = :a
    [e, *a] = [:a, 2, "g"]
  e = :b
    [e, *a] = [:b, 2, "g"]
a = ["r", 2]
  e = :a
    [e, *a] = [:a, "r", 2]
  e = :b
    [e, *a] = [:b, "r", 2]
a = ["r", "g"]
  e = :a
    [e, *a] = [:a, "r", "g"]
  e = :b
    [e, *a] = [:b, "r", "g"]
```